# Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS (Developer Edition): Custom Themes Using Demo Themes

Tags: arcgis-online

**How to I navigate to the ~/client/stemapp/themes to start creating custom themes, widgets and controllers?**

I have been following the protocol (numbered list below) that highlights on their site along with a youtube video, but I have yet to figure out how to enable the environment that will allow me to start editing source code and customizing as shown in the snippet below.

1. Go to ~/client/stemapp/themes, where the DemoTheme folder is
       located.
2. Make a copy of the DemoTheme folder in the same directory, and
       rename it NewTheme.
3. Update the following properties in the manifest.json file: Name:NewTheme

   ```
        -Note: This value must be the same as the name of the theme folder.

        -Label: New Theme
   ```

   4. Update the localization files in the nls folder as needed. Make sure
          the _themeLabel property in the strings.js file has been updated to
          the name of the new theme.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need an ArcGIS Online API Developer License